# Using polyglossia, microtype and newcomputermodern with LuaLaTeX results in "0.0.0.0.0" being added

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, microtype, newcomputermodern

Using the packages `polyglossia`, `microtype` and `newcomputermodern` when compiling with LuaLaTeX leads to ".0.0.0.0.0" being added. This occurs at the beginning of the document and with section numbering. Is there a way to circumvent this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For some reasons, something is badly interpreted at font changes when `microtype` is examining a few characters: the backslash, the braces, the angle brackets and a five characters in the PUA for a total of ten, which is the number of `.0` extra output you get. It seems a combined action by `polyglossia` and `microtype`.

Comment: polyglossia forces the harfbuzz renderer, and there is a bad interaction with microtype. The next luaotfload version will resolve this problem, until then use `\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` before polyglossia, or consider to use babel.

Comment: This has been in fixed in `microtype` v3.0. (You'll get some warnings now, but that's a different issue...)

Answer (score 7):

That's fun!

I am not sure you are supposed to use the package for fontspec-driven format. In the README file (`...texlive2021/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/newcomputermodern/README`) it says to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Book}
\setsansfont{NewCMSans10-Book}
\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Book}
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\end{document}
```

which seems to have no problem... but well, I agree that the behavior is at least strange.

Answer (score 5):

Loading `fontspec` explicitly and loading `newcomputermodern` *before* `polyglossia` also works, i.e., produces the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % load *before* polyglossia
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\end{document}
```